# How to exclude forms from processing by Hide Submit module?

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

According to module description this is possible.

However I didn't find how to do it and I did not able to exclude form by any way, e.g:

http://drupalcode.org/project/hide_submit.git/commit/8aab1ab

Comment: The 7.x-1.x branch is very different to the 7.x-2.x branch, and it looks like you've got the former installed. The description on the module page refers to the latter, which is probably where the discrepancy in functionality is coming from

Comment: @Clive, yes I have 7.x-2.0

Comment: My mistake, 2 secs I'll put an answer in...

Answer (score 3):

The 2.x branch introduced `hook_hide_submit_alter()` which can be implemented to exclude certain forms based on the current path:

```
function MYMODULE_hide_submit_alter($hide_submit_settings) {

  // IMPORTANT NOTE: given the way module_invoke_all and array_merge work you
  // should not modify and return the original array. Instead create a new one
  // and add only the keys you care about. If two modules implement this hook
  // and try to modify the same values then the default will be used instead.
  $altered_settings = array();  

  // Disable the module for my special form page.
  if (arg(0) == 'my-special-form') {
    $altered_settings['hide_submit']['hide_submit_status'] = FALSE;
  }

  return $altered_settings;
}
```

There doesn't look to be a way to turn the functionality off for a specific form, just by path. Might be worth a feature request on the module issue queue if that's something you'd like to see.

Comment: I would upvote but I used all my votes for the day so I'll go to bed :)

Answer (score 1):

The commit you link to is from Sun, 19 Apr 2009. That code no longer exists in the latest drupal 7 version.

After having a quick look at the latest drupal 7 code there doesn't seem to be such a feature in it anymore.

Comment: Have a peek at the hide_submit.api.php file, the solution is documented in there in the latest stable release (I used it myself a couple of weeks ago, works a treat) :)

Comment: I did the same research and I can confirm it

Comment: Nice, so you can do it, there just isn't a setting in the UI anymore.

Comment: Yeah...that module confuses the **** out of me; if I'm being honest, I actually ditched the module altogether and wrote my own version of the code soon after implementing that hook. More trouble than it's worth

Comment: @rooby IMHO it should be done on client side too. Using a custom hook is overkill for me and solution from api file sucks too